# Pulling and pushing columns in one specific width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

:)

I have a DIV[B] that is *col-xs-6 col-md-push-5 col-md-7*. DIV[A] is *col-xs-6 col-md-pull-7 col-md-5*. DIV[B] comes before DIV[A] in the code so the pull/push makes sense.

It shows like this:

*Large: [A][B]*

*Medium: [A][B]*

*Small: [B][A]*

*X-Small: [B][A]*

I want to make X-SMall [A][B], leaving just small as [B][A].
I tried a lot (pushing and pulling SM, XS) but I just couldn't do it... It always breaks one of the others.

Is there a way for me to do that? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just make A first, and use the `pull-0` or `push-0` classes.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-push-7 col-sm-5 col-lg-push-0 col-md-push-0">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-pull-5 col-sm-7 col-lg-pull-0 col-md-pull-0">B</div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/wraA182sM2

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much. :))))

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep the DIV[B] DIV[A] order, you would have to set the push/pull for xs, reset the push/pull for the small size, and then set the push/pull again for md+ size.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-6 col-sm-push-0 col-md-push-5">
            <p>Col B</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-pull-6 col-sm-pull-0 col-md-pull-7">
            <p>Col A</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/atadams/pen/NNoWYy)

BTW, the `col-lg-push-0` in @Skelly's answer is unnecessary. The `col-md-push-0` applies to lg size.